# How to send image to server using HTTP Post

Tags: java, eclipse, image, post

I have an image which I would like to use for SAP's scene text recognition. According to the sample provided code of SAP's scene text recognition API, I need to send the image's content as part of the URL. I managed to send the file using POST method but I cannot get the correct text from the image when I call the API. When I try the API with Postman, it works perfectly fine. So, I think the problem lies in my code.

This below is my code to get the image content. 
[image: My code to get the image content]

This is what I did to send the image using POST. 
[image]

If my codes work, when I call the SAP scene text recognition URL, it should give me the plate number of the bus. But instead, I am getting other alphabets which are not related to my image at all.

Please advise for improvement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think that an image file is text?

Comment: I know it's not. But I just don't know how to get the content of an image. And to add on, I am still a beginner. Please advise me what to improve so that I can learn. Thank you! :D

Comment: well for a start read as bytes